# Pattern for configuring @BeforeClass and @Before Methods

Tags: java, junit4

I have now a situation where I have something like the following:

```
public class SomeTest extends AbstractMyTest {

    @Test
    public void something() {
        //Test something, related to the AbstractMyTest config
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfiguration() {
        return "myConfigFile.ini";
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractMyTest {
    @Before
    public void before() {
        //Do some init stuff that calls getConfiguration()...
    }

    abstract String getConfiguration();
}
```

Now, I am considering of getting rid of the AbstractMyTest Class and have something like the following:

```
@MyTestConfig(value="myConfigFile.ini")
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void something() {
        //Test something, related to the AbstractMyTest config
    }
}
```

So I might have a custom Runner that does what the AbstractMyTest class was responsible for. I would love to be able to do some stuff in a @BeforeClass or @Before manner without having to do it in every TestClass. How would such a Runner be structured?

Comment: Avoid the custom runner, this is not what they are meant for. Rather use a `Rule` but for your case, the property approach was fine. What made you change?

Comment: I'm considering the change in order to avoid inheritance and stick to the Annotation based programming pattern. It's not a discussion about which can work, rather which is more appropiate to give it to developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand why do you need a custom `Runner` here.

It looks like you can use [`Rule`s](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/Rule.html) to do exactly what you want. In particular, take a look at [`ExternalResource` rule](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html):

```
public class SomeTest {
    @Rule
    public MyTestRule myRule = new MyTestRule("myConfigFile.ini");
    ...
}

public class MyTestRule extends ExternalResource {
    ...
    protected void before() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks great. Will test it right away, but it seems that it is just what I need...